# MPMusicPlayerController in ViewController does not play in applicationDidEnterBackground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I was able to get this appDelegate method to work when I simply had a UIWindow - I set app's plist file property to play audio in the background, however after introducing ViewController, the audio fades out when I background app.

Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    AVAudioSession* audio = [[AVAudioSession alloc] init];
    [audio setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    [audio setActive: YES error: nil];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get info on background tasks from here  [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)